# Azure - Function App - VNet Integration - Adding Virtual Network to Web App - UpdateOnResourceNotAllowedWithApiVersion

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-virtual-network-gateway

I have followed this guide to *Enable virtual network integration* in my Azure Function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli#enable-virtual-network-integration

At first it looks good and my Virtual network with a Virtual network gateway configured with Point to Site VPN shows up as expected:

[image]

However on add it fails with the following message:

[image]

If I then look at Activity log it does say Succeeded.

[image]

Looking at VNet Integration for the Azure Function it has been set up and I get `GATEWAY STATUS Online` but `CERTIFICATE STATUS Certificates not in sync`.

[image]

Looking at the Networking tab it also says `VNet integration Off`.

[image]

Now looking at the subscription that has the virtual network I did receive the following error the first time I tried to set up the VLAN:

> Operation name Creates or updates a VirtualNetworkGateway
>
> Error code UpdateOnResourceNotAllowedWithApiVersion
>
> Message Resource /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/my-virtual-network-gateway
> cannot be updated using API version 2016-09-01 since it uses the
> property VpnClientConfiguration AAD authentication parameters which
> has been set using a higher API version 2019-04-01. Please use api
> version greater than or equal to 2019-04-01 to update the resource.

[image]

Does this mean that Azure GUI uses `API version 2016-09-01`? Can I set the GUI to use `API version 2019-04-01` or how can I manually add the configuration needed to make this work?

I have tried to use Sync Network from App Service Plan Network GUI but it fails as well.

[image]

There I get the following errors:

> Operation name Creates or updates a VirtualNetworkGateway
>
> Error code UpdateOnResourceNotAllowedWithApiVersion
>
> Message Resource /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/my-virtual-network-gateway
> cannot be updated using API version 2016-09-01 since it uses the
> property VpnClientConfiguration AAD authentication parameters which
> has been set using a higher API version 2019-04-01. Please use api
> version greater than or equal to 2019-04-01 to update the resource.

And:

> Operation name Generate VpnClient package for virtualNetworkGateway
>
> Error code VpnClientCMakGenerationNotSupportedForVpnClientProtocol
>
> Message Legacy Cmak generation is not supported for gateway id
> /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/my-virtual-network-gateway
> when vpn client protocol OpenVPN is configured. Please use vpn profile
> package option instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I could create a new Function App from another subscription but located in the same region as the Virtual network that I wanted to use. This meant that the Virtual network gateway not had to be used. I had to create a new Subnet for it. I used the same App Service Plan as a current Web App used, `Standard S1 (100 total ACU, 1.75 GB memory, 1 vCPU)`.

[image]

[image]

**Original:**

Created a new Function App located in the same subscription and region as the Virtual network that I wanted to use.

[image]

[image]

From here I could use `Add VNet Integration` and select which subnet I wanted to use. When doing this everything worked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]